# How to verify a software package using SHA256 checksums and PGP or GnuPG keys, on Windows?

Tags: windows, encryption, gnupg, digital-signature

I'd like to verify the Vagrant installation method using their recommended verification method. On the installation page it says:

> You can find the SHA256 checksums for Vagrant 1.7.4 online and you can
>   verify the checksums signature file which has been signed using
>   HashiCorp's GPG key.

What steps are necessary to complete this? And what de facto standard software should I use? Gpg4win seems to be one of them.

Can someone please explain this process in an easy to understand manner?

Comment: Hi user2476265. Based on your mentioning Gpg4win, I assume you are looking for a solution that works on Windows? Also, since questions seeking off-site resources are off topic, I edited it such that answers should more directly address what you are looking for (how to do it, rather than where to find out how to do it). Should you feel that these edits changed your intent in any way, by all means feel free to [edit] further, keeping our [site's scope](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) in mind.